# PHPStorm with Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpstorm

I have a problem with my PHPStorm IDE, the version is 7

this is my First time using Google App Engine on PHPStorm IDE
I choose the PHPStorm

when i set up the GAE project with the following tutorial :

http://goo.gl/LTEv8R

i click Run button, and then show nothing.
what's wrong with the project ?
everyone tell me this ? thanks !!
by the way, my php-cgi installed by Homebrew (brew install --with-cgi --with-debug php54)
and google-php-sdk installed by the official app : Google App Engine Launcher, it includes sdk in the directory of the App Contents (GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/google_appengine)

Screenshot
http://i42.tinypic.com/122f51s.png

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the app though the web browser after you've clicked run.

Open chrome and go to 127.0.0.1:8080 and you should see "Hello World".

Comment: ya, i know but i got nothing when going to 127.0.0.1:8080 or localhost:8080. Actually, i try to click run many times, but nothing happened ... In the tutorial, it shows some RED text after clicked, but i get nothing.

Comment: i found it !!! the problem is that the google app engine runs the first time, it will ask you to turn on automatic update on PYTHON (in Terminal) . After you answer it, all will be solved.